# How to work with foreign key for an object which is both principal and dependent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two objects in the database and the relationship between them as below. I follow the instruction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee794150(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a new Contact and Account which are a new principal and dependent object respectively. Below is my code.

This works fine one way when `newContact` and `newAccount` are created. The `business_contact_uid` and `business_address_uid` show the `uid` of the `newContact`. However, the `aid` of `newContact` is `null`. <-- I want it to show the `uid` of the `newAccount` as well.

So what I understand is that I created `newContact` as a principal object and `newAccount` as a dependent one. Is there anyway to let EF know that `aid` relationship as well when they are created?

```
using (var frontendDb = new salon_database_test())
{
     var newContact = new Contact
     {
         first_name = model.FirstName,
         last_name = model.LastName,
         email = model.Email,
     };
     frontendDb.contacts.Add(newContact);

     var newAccount = new Account
     {
         name = model.BusinessName,
         country_id = model.Country,
         BusinessContact = newContact,
         BusinessAddress = newContact
     };
     frontendDb.accounts.Add(newAccount);

     frontendDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image]

Below are the `Contact` class and `Account` class

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(Order=1)]
    public int uid { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int? aid { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember, ForeignKey("aid")]
    public virtual Account account_owner { get; set; }

    //..others..
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(Order=1)]
    public int uid { get; set; }

    // Address of the business 
    public int? business_address_uid { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember, ForeignKey("business_address_uid")]
    public virtual Contact BusinessAddress { get; set; }

    // Contact details for the main contact of the account (business owner)
    public int? business_contact_uid { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember, ForeignKey("business_contact_uid")]
    public virtual Contact BusinessContact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? Can i have a feedback?

Comment: @PaoloCosta I have tried but it doesn't work. I guess my problem is a two-way navigation, not one-to-many relationship.